# I can't print hello world in Vs code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, linker-errors, cs50

So I started Harvard's online Computer science class and in the first problem set I needed to print Hello World in C, I followed all the instructions correctly but when I try to compile the program it gives me:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 1
```

I'd be so thankful if someone fixed my issue as I am learning CS at home and I have no one to turn to for help :)

[Screenshot of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeyJu.png)

Comment: I can't see a makefile in your directory when looking at the provided screenshot

Comment: @AJB so I followed these instructions: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/1/hello/      but when I try to compile the program ( make hello ) I get the error.

Comment: looks like you haven't saved the file (the white dot on the tab means you have unsaved changes).

Comment: @yano wow.... well that fixed it! Thank you so much man.

Comment: Please provide code, not pictures.  Providing code is useful for others to find this question using google and for us to paste and run it.

Comment: @alinsoar the code is just a hello world program.. I didnt save it before compiling so thats why I got errors.

Comment: Visual Studio Code *has* a setting to auto save before compiling. They just thought it best to have it turned off by default...